# Do I need a stamp for my USPA license?

Tags: skydiving

A few weeks ago I finally finished all of my USPA A license requirements. My instructor signed off the final things and even the card but forgot to put the stamp itself on the form.

I was about to send the form off to get my A license card but am hesitant without the stamp. Do I need the stamp to have it processed? More importantly, will I be able to use my paper form as the temporary A license without the stamp?

I normally wouldnt have an issue just going back to see him, but I am overseas for several months and really wanted to jump when I take leave.

I'm hoping to find an instructor or someone with personal experience with this... Thanks!

Comment: I can't answer your question, but the [USPA licensing page](http://www.uspa.org/USPAMembers/LicensesampRatings/Licenses/tabid/87/Default.aspx) has a phone number and email address for licensing questions. That should get you an answer if no one here can help you.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a USPA AFF, tandem, and static line instructor.  Your signed and completed A-License Proficiency Card is valid and USPA will process it without the stamp.  You only need the stamp if you want to go to another dropzone and use your card as a temporary license.

The proficiency card is only valid for 60 days after the date it was completed, so don't waste time sending it in.  The last I heard, USPA is taking 3-4 weeks to process license applications.

Edit to add:  Don't send in the actual card.  You can mail a photocopy, fax it in, or scan it and email it to membership@uspa.org.  Faxing or emailing will get you your official license a few days faster.